# WebAPI caching for http Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, http-caching

As a part of our refactoring and move to WebApi 2, we are thinking of caching our responses. Based on my research OOB only the Get & Head are supported, however all our controllers only expose POST methods, are there are custom libraries or articles that can help us with implementing caching for POST actions ?

Comment: First, Web API doesn't have caching. Second, a POST only controller is a .... weird controller as far as REST goes. POST actions are supposed to *create* new resources, not return them. They are supposed to *invalidate* caches. Intermediate proxies, caches and browsers will *not* cache your response anyway. Are you trying to emulate a web service?

Comment: HTTP never supported caching for POST

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh caching Web Services requires caching POST by necessity. Several caching products do this for the endpoints, but intermediate caches, proxies, can't