# WebAPI core 2.0 Cache by post params

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0, httpresponsecache, asp.net-core-2.1

I am building an pure json api and I want to cache response according to post params. Is there any similar way like VaryByQueryKeys?
Maybe some custom cache middleware or?

Of course I can use MemoryCache but wonder maybe there is some "build in" practice.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread here:
[WebAPI caching for http Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596582/webapi-caching-for-http-post)

Do you really need HttpPost request to fulfill your requirements? Have you considered using GET request and then leverage client side caching?

Comment: Yes our API is pure JSON api with using POST 99%

Comment: For pure Json API with POST method, you will need to cache data on server side using MemCache or Redis or any other caching provider.

Comment: What is disadantage to use just MemryCache vs MemCache?

Answer (score 0):

Of course shouldn't expect caching in post API

But look at this sample code on special controller not in middleware and it is not "build in"

May be useful

```
  public class XController : Controller
   {
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    public XController(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<YourCustomModel>> Post([FromBody] ParamtersModel value)
    {
        string cacheKey = value.Id.ToString();
        IEnumerable<YourCustomModel> cacheEntry = await _cache.GetOrCreate(cacheKey, async entry =>
        {
            entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
           
            IEnumerable<YourCustomModel> result = await ... your method calling for first time to getting in cache
            return result;

        });
        return cacheEntry;
    }

   }
```